# Are all JavaScript object property names (except Symbols) implicitly converted to strings? Even numbers?

Tags: javascript

MDN states here

> JavaScript object property names (keys) can **only** be strings or
> Symbols.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#object_initializers

However, it is stated here

> Additionally, you can use a **numeric** or string literal for the name of a property or nest an object inside another.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#literals

These are seemingly conflicting statements. My question is,

1. What is MDN documentation actually saying here? Am I missing something?
2. What is allowed and what is not allowed as property names?
3. If object property names can only be strings then does that mean numbers get implicitly converted to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, number keys are converted to strings.

```js
const obj = {2: "hello"}
const keys = Object.keys(obj)
console.log(keys)
console.log(typeof keys[0])
console.log(obj[2])
console.log(obj['2'])

// that's true for arrays too
const arr = ["world"]
console.log(Object.keys(arr))
console.log(arr["0"])
```

Answer (score 3):

The latter is not about keys per se but rather about what can be used as a key in **object literals** (so that the interpreter accepts a literal in your code) .

Take

```
var o = {}; 
var p = {}; 

o[p] = 1;
```

What key is used to store `1` in `o`? It's `'[object Object]'`, as this is just `p` promoted to a string (`p.toString()`)

On the other hand

```
var p = {};
var o = { p: 1, 7: 2 };
```

Despite `p` being an object, in the object literal `{ p: 1, 7: 2 }`, `p` is just a string, the key name. The `7` is promoted to string and makes the second key. The two keys are then `'p'` and `'7'`.

However if a key is enclosed in brackets

```
var p = {};
var o = { [p]: 1, 7: 2 };
```

its actual value is used, which means that now, `o` has two keys, `'[object Object]'` and `'7'`.

**Edit** Regaring the question about `[object Object]`. The default implementation of the `.toString()` for an empty object returns this exact string, `[object Object]`.

```
var p = {}
console.log( p.toString() );
```

Thus, if an empty object is used as a key, the key name is `[object Object]`. Interestingly, overrding the `toString()` changes the key to the `toString()`'s value:

```js
var o = {}
var p = {
   toString: function() {
      return 'foo bar';
   }
}

console.log( p.toString() );

o[p] = 1;

console.log( Object.keys(o) );
```

In the above example, the indexing object `toString()` has been overridden to provide an alternate value (`foo bar`) and thus, using `p` as an index creates `foo bar` key in `o` (which is shown by calling `Object.keys(o)`).

Comment: I could not understand the '[object Object]' part of your answer, is there a way I can test that? Your elaboration would be appreciated.

Comment: A default implementation of toString for an empty object {} is just [object Object].

Comment: Updated my answer, hope this makes things more clear.

Comment: It took me a little time but after reading your answer a few times and experimenting side by side, I understood it. Your answer is very comprehensive and detailed, it not only answered my question but also made learn about some other important aspects of this topic. Thank you very much.